# Keyman developer 10 won't match rules in Odia script

Tags: unicode, keyboard, ime, keyman, keyman-developer

I'm making a custom keyboard for Oriya/ Odia script with Keyman developer 10 but it won't do contextual substitutions when all the input is in Odia script. For example

```
+ [K_K] > U+0B15
+ [K_T] > U+0B24
U+0B15 + U+0B24 > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
"a" + "b" > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
U+0B15 + [K_C] > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
```

When I test his, I get the desired output when I type 'ab' or 'kc' but not with 'kt'. Any help to explain why line 3 won't work but line 4 does will be appreciated.

I do get this error sometimes when Targets is set to 'any' rather than 'windows'

```
warning 209A: The rule will never be matched because its key code is never fired.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is you are trying to match on a Unicode value instead of a keystroke on line 3:

```
U+0B15 + U+0B24 > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
```

Instead of `U+0B24`, which is a Unicode character, you need to [match on the keystroke](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/guide/rules), for example:

```
+ [K_K] > U+0B15
+ [K_T] > U+0B24
U+0B15 + [K_T] > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
```

As this third rule has a longer context (`U+0B15`), it takes [precedence over the second rule](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/guide/groups).

An alternate way to solve this issue is to use a [post-processing group](https://help.keyman.com/developer/language/guide/groups). In this model, the output from the first group is fed into the context of the second group. Note that the second group does not include a `using keys` clause.

```
group(main) using keys

+ [K_K] > U+0B15
+ [K_T] > U+0B24
match > use(post)

group(post)

U+0B15 U+0B24 > U+0B15 U+0B4D U+0B24
```

Comment: So matching by letters is supported only in basic Latin? I tested that in cyrillic too and it won't work.

What I'm trying to achieve is when two consonants are typed I'd like to automatically U+0B4D in between. So you suggest I do it this way?

store(consonants) 'bcdef'
store(consonant_keys) [K_B] [K_C] [K_D] [K_E] [K_F]
any(consonants) any(consonant_keys) > index(consonants,1) U+0B4D index((consonant_keys,2)

Comment: @coldbreeze16, The key identifiers are not really basic Latin; as you are matching on a key identified by "a" which is shorthand for [K_A], which is mnemonic for key C01. The code is nearly right, just needs a `+` delimiter: `any(consonants) + any(consonant_keys) > index(consonants,1) U+0B4D index(consonant_keys,2)`. You can also consider doing post-processing with a secondary group: `+ any(consonant_keys) > index(consonants, 1)` `match > use(post)` `group(post)` `any(consonant) any(consonant) > context(1) U+0B4D context(2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been using a program in Win to type my langauge in Windows, recently I migrated to Mac but needed the same layout. This was a life saver. Already accomplished what I needed, I'll have to delve deeper into these post processing groups.